# JPA CascadeType.REMOVE not deleting children of a relashionship

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

In my project I have the classes reported below, with a bidirectional relationship mapping. 
When I try to delete the parent of the relationship (in my case DataProvider), the main object is deleted, while the children do not get deleted.
I have also already tested several other combinations of annotations, none of which seem to work (orphanRemoval, @ElementDependent, optional = false, ...).

Delete is done via a query like this:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM DataProvider dp WHERE ... ");
q.executeUpdate();
```

Anyone can please suggest something?

```
@Entity(name = "DataProvider")
public class DataProviderImpl implements DataProvider {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    // ...

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=RestMethodImpl.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="dataProvider", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private List<RestMethod> methods;


    public DataProviderImpl() {
        super();
        this.id = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    @Override
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public List<RestMethod> getMethods() {
        return methods;
    }
    @Override
    public void setMethods(List<RestMethod> methods) {
        this.methods = methods;
    }
}
```

.

```
public interface DataProvider {
    public int getId();
    public void setId(int id);
    public String getName();
    public void setName(String name);
    public List<RestMethod> getMethods();
    public void setMethods(List<RestMethod> methods);
}
```

.

```
@Entity(name = "RestMethod")
public class RestMethodImpl implements RestMethod {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String nickname;
    // ...

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=DataProviderImpl.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="dataProviderId")
    private DataProvider dataProvider;

    public RestMethodImpl() {
        super();
        this.id = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    @Override
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Override
    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }
    @Override
    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }
    @Override
    public DataProvider getDataProvider() {
        return dataProvider;
    }
    @Override
    public void setDataProvider(DataProvider dataProvider) {
        this.dataProvider = dataProvider;
    }
}
```

.

```
public interface RestMethod  {
    public int getId();
    public void setId(int id);
    public String getNickname();
    public void setNickname(String nickname);
    public DataProvider getDataProvider();
    public void setDataProvider(DataProvider dataProvider);
}
```

.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JPA: DELETE WHERE does not delete children and throws an exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825484/jpa-delete-where-does-not-delete-children-and-throws-an-exception)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JPA OneToMany not deleting child](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011519/jpa-onetomany-not-deleting-child)

Comment: Well it actually looks similar to the first link (the DELETE WHERE issue), even if in my case does not throw any exception.
I think I should follow suggestion of that thread anyway..

Comment: From what I can see, you are specifying that RestMethodImpl is the owner of the relationship, since DataProviderImpl states that the relationsship is mapped by (and thus owned) by the other side.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Smutje link I changed the query to the following (which worked):

```
Iterator itr = itemsToDelete.iterator();
int deleted = 0;
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    em.remove(itr.next());
    deleted++;
}
```

Unfortunately it may not be very fast for bulk delete, but at least for simple delete queries it cascades properly.