# What is the best way to bulk delete rows in JPA while also cascading the delete to child records

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.1, bulk-delete

I'm trying to do bulk delete in my entities, and the best solution will be to go with `CriteriaDelete`. But `CriteriaDelete` does not cascade (at least not for me).

So, it seems like the only solution which I have is to do select first and delete each element separately. Which does not seems wrong to me.

Is anyone have a better idea of how to do bulk delete? Is it actually a better way?

If it helps I'm using EclipseLink 2.5.2.

Comment: Can you use an `ON DELETE` constraint in your database?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The options are:

1. use the cascade.Remove setting on the mapping, loading entities
   and calling em.remove on each
2. Use bulk delete on the main entity and have the "ON DELETE
   CASCADE" database option set so that the database will cascade the
   delete for you.  EclipseLink has a @CascadeOnDelete annotation that
   lets it know the "ON DELETE CASCADE" is set on a relationship, or to
   create it if using JPA for DDL generation: http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_cascadeondelete.htm
3. Use multiple bulk deletes to remove children that might be referenced before removing the main entity.  For example: "Delete FROM Child c where c.parent = (select p from Parent P where [delete-conditions])"  and "Delete FROM Parent p where [delete-conditions]"  See section 10.2.4 of http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/toplink/OTLCG/queries.htm#OTLCG94370 for details.

Answer (score 10):

### How does the JPA CriteriaDelete work

A JPA `CriteriaDelete` statement generates a JPQL bulk delete statement, that's parsed to an SQL bulk delete statement.

So, the following JPA `CriteriaDelete` statement:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    
CriteriaDelete<PostComment> delete = builder.createCriteriaDelete(PostComment.class);

Root<T> root = delete.from(PostComment.class);

int daysValidityThreshold = 3;

delete.where(
    builder.and(
        builder.equal(
            root.get("status"), 
            PostStatus.SPAM
        ),
        builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(
            root.get("updatedOn"), 
            Timestamp.valueOf(
                LocalDateTime
                .now()
                .minusDays(daysValidityThreshold)
            )
        )
    )
);

int deleteCount = entityManager.createQuery(delete).executeUpdate();
```

generates this SQL delete query:

```
DELETE FROM
    post_comment
WHERE
    status = 2 AND
    updated_on <= '2020-08-06 10:50:43.115'
```

So, there is no entity-level cascade since the delete is done using the SQL statement, not via the `EntityManager`.

### Bulk Delete Cascading

To enable cascading when executing bulk delete, you need to use DDL-level cascade when declaring the FK constraints.

```
ALTER TABLE post_comment 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_POST_COMMENT_POST_ID
FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES post 
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Now, when executing the following bulk delete statement:

```
DELETE FROM
    post
WHERE
    status = 2 AND
    updated_on <= '2020-08-02 10:50:43.109'
```

The DB will delete the `post_comment` records referencing the `post` rows that got deleted.

The best way to execute DDL is via an automatic schema migration tool, like [Flyway](https://vladmihalcea.com/flyway-database-schema-migrations/), so the Foreign Key definition should reside in a migration script.

If you are generating the migration scripts using the HBM2DLL tool, then, in the `PostComment` class, you can use the following mapping to generate the aforementioned DDL statement:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_POST_COMMENT_POST_ID"))
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private Post post;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really care about the time it takes to perform this bulk delete, I suggest you use JPQL to delete your entities. When you issue a `DELETE` JPQL query, it will directly issue a delete on those entities without retrieving them in the first place.

```
int deletedCount = entityManager.createQuery("DELETE FROM Country").executeUpdate();
```

You can even do conditional deletes based on some parameters on those entities using Query API like below

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("DELETE FROM Country c 
                              WHERE c.population < :p");
int deletedCount = query.setParameter(p, 100000).executeUpdate();
```

`executeUpdate` will return the number of deleted rows once the operation is complete.

If you've proper cascading type in place in your entities like `CascadeType.ALL` (or) `CascadeType.REMOVE`, then the above query will do the trick for you.

```
@Entity
class Employee {

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Address address;

}
```

For more details, have a look at [this](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/delete) and [this](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/delete).

Comment: JPA will not cascade the bulk delete http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825484/jpa-delete-where-does-not-delete-children-and-throws-an-exception

Answer (score 2):

JPQL `BULK DELETE` (whether using string-based JPQL or using Criteria JPQL) is not intended to cascade (i.e follow the cascade type settings for fields). If you want cascading then you either set up the datastore to use real `FOREIGN KEY`s, or you pull back the objects to delete and call `EntityManager.remove()`.

Comment: what do you mean by " to use real FOREIGN KEY" ? could you elaborate?

Comment: add a FOREIGN KEY constraint in your RDBMS table definitions, and these can be "ON DELETE CASCADE"

Comment: `EntityManager.remove()` is not a good idea when you need to delete so many entities because you're unnecessarily loading those entities just to able to call remove on each one of them. Using JPQL, you can easily avoid those `select` queries and reduce the round-trips to db server :)

Comment: @NeilStockton I have defined FKs for each entity, they are present in my schema, but even if i set``CascadeType.REMOVE` on relation, on schema i have `ON DELETE NO ACTION`

Comment: Have a look at my answer, you can set cascading types on entities without explicit relationship between db tables. If not you have to write triggers for delete on parent table to delete all child tables or you have to go with the old way of deleting children first and then parent manually from code one after the other which is pretty tiresome :-)

Comment: If you have ON DELETE NO ACTION then the RDBMS will do no cascading when a ROW is deleted. If you delete through em.remove then the JPA impl will do the cascading for you. You decide which route fits best with your situation, can't be simpler

Comment: @NeilStockton is it any way in jpa or eclipselink configuration to enforce this constrain?

Comment: You can do that using annotations while defining entities