# Is there "CASCADE ON UPDATE" functionality in Spring Boot for DB level?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

How can I create CASCADE ON UPDATE funcionality Database level using Hibernate annotations? Similar to "@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)". I don't mean CascadeType enums.

Comment: Need more information on what you're trying to do

Comment: @KeshavramKuduwa I just want to create a foreign key with "cascade on update" via Spring Boot.

Comment: See  Solution 2 in answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72144075/jpa-cascading-delete-fails-with-custom-delete-method/72145171#72145171. You can  define custom FK constraint  for JoinColumn annotation, specify ON UPDATE CASCADE instead DELETE

Comment: @Eugene Thank you. I didn't know "foreignKeyDefinition" usage. This is the exact solution I search.