# JPA Container managed entity update after persist

Tags: jpa

Hello I am having problem with auto generated primary key of entity in JPA. I am persisting the entity and trying to get the id value out of it, but it returns null even though I am doing flush. I am using latest glassfish, JPA, netbeans, EJB 3

```
public class CatchesEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    (...)




    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "DBF")
    private EntityManager em;

    (...)
    public void randomMethod()
    {
         CatchesEntity catchEntity = new CatchesEntity();
         em.persist(catchEntity);
         em.flush();
         System.out.println("CATCH ID: "+catchEntity.getId());
```

I get NULL

Answer (score 2):

Calling `flush()` will send most instructions to the DB, but not the `INSERT`commands that are generated on `commit()`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275111/correct-use-of-flush-in-jpa-hibernate) for more info.

You seem to be working with container-managed transactions, so in general the commit will be performed when the method returns.

If you want to force a commit inside a method, you can disable CMT either on the bean or on the one method and use a `UserTransaction`:

```
tx.begin();
...
em.persist();
tx.commit();
```