# ConstraintViolationException during transaction for entity with index

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, oracle10g

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product",
        indexes = {@Index(name = "productIndex", columnList = "family, group, type", unique = true)})
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "family")
    private String family;

    @Column(name = "group")
    private String group;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

}
```

And I'm trying to empty its database table, and insert new rows:

```
@Transactional
public void update(List<Product> products) {
    productRepository.deleteAll();
    productRepository.batchInsert(products);
}
```

`ProductRepository` is:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long>, BatchRepository<Product> { }
```

And `BatchRepository`:

```
@Repository
public class BatchRepository<T> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public int batchInsert(List<T> entities) {
        int count = 0;

        for (T entity : entities) {
            entityManager.persist(entity);
            count++;

            if (count % 2000 == 0) {
                entityManager.flush();
                entityManager.clear();
            }
        }

        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.clear();

        return count;
    }

}
```

Trying to perform the insertion fails with `java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (productIndex) violated`, but shouldn't the previous deletion make this violation impossible to happen?

### Update #1

```
@Transactional
public void update(List<Product> products) {
    productRepository.deleteAll();
    insertProducts(products);
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void insertProducts(List<Product> products) {
    productRepository.batchInsert(products);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've found a few answers that address your problem.

### Solution 1 - [#link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62637878/865499)

Annotate your transactional method with:

```java
@Modifying(flushAutomatically = true)
```

That will make sure that `deleteAll` call is flushed, ie. indexes are updated, before the following `batchInsert` call.

### Solution 2 - [#link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72452608/865499)

Use `deleteAllInBatch` from `JpaRepository` instead of `deleteAll`.

### Solution 3 - [#link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50370469/865499)

Manually invoke `flush` after `deleteAll` in the transactional method.

### Solution 4

A more custom SQL solution would be to batch insert new records into a temporary table. Then you can either:

1. Drop the existing `product` table and rename the temporary one into `product`.
2. `SELECT * FROM #temp_table INTO product` - put all records from temp table to `product`.

Let me know if any of that works. Good luck!

Comment: solution 2 works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to me, you should perform `deleteAll()` operation separately as you are using `@Transactional` annotation and changes are not committed until the annotated function successfully returns. Because of that, your primary keys are still duplicated.

Comment: that's probably it, but I do both in the same transaction because I want it to undo changes if any error occurrs. Is there someway to update the indexes?

Comment: You can write a different method  for insertion of data and add @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) annotation on it. Call the method in your update(...) method then.

Comment: your suggestion does not work

Comment: Can you share the code snippet, how you implemented it.

Comment: updated the question with it!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you put an unique constraint in the table index "productIndex"

You are attempting to delete all records in the first line

```
@Transactional
public void update(List<Product> products) {
 productRepository.deleteAll();
 productRepository.batchInsert(products);
}
```

but I think the records remain in the index named "productIndex"

Comment: yeah, that is basically what is happening, but I'm looking for a way to update that index table as well... I thought it was automatically handled

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this code

```
public void update(List<Product> products) {
 deleteAll()
 insertProducts(products);
}

@Transactional
public void deleteAll() {
 productRepository.deleteAll();
}

@Transactional
public void insertProducts(List<Product> products) {
 productRepository.batchInsert(products);
}
```

Comment: with this code, deletion is done even if insertion fails. This is not what I want